# Configuring Oracle Weblogic JMS resource adapter on IBM websphere

Tags: jms, websphere, weblogic, resource-adapter

problem: MDB running on Websphere server listens to a queue on Weblogic server

I have deployed the wljmsra.rar on the WAS server, but have run into multiple roadblocks (and been down different rabbit holes) trying to solve the problem.

- tried the non JCA route by adding the weblogic server as a new JMS provider. I am able to establish connection but the MDB ends up using the IBM sib resource adapter to talk to weblogic and I get the following exception

  *The exception is: javax.resource.spi.InvalidPropertyException: CWSJR1181E: The JMS activation specification has invalid values - the reason(s) for failing to validate the JMS activation specification are: [CWSJR1192E: JMS activation specs using a destination type of queue must have a destination of type [com.ibm.websphere.sib.api.jms.JmsQueue] but the destination passed was of type [weblogic.jms.common.DistributedDestinationImpl]]*
- Tried the wljmsra resource adapter with J2C connection factory, J2C administered object and J2C activation spec. it appears that this one somehow uses the local JNDI context and not the the weblogic JNDI and when looking up the target JNDI names of the connectionfactory/queue and fails with a nameNotfound exception
- Tried the cobmination of both the JMS provider and the JCA resource adapter (yep... sounds crazy right) but this one gives me the following exception:

  *javax.resource.NotSupportedException: J2EE GJRA-02300: cause = Endpoint defined with transaction attribute Required must be configured with a XA capable JMS connection factory; action = Please check the configuration of the connection factory specified for this endpoint*

My preference would be to go down the JCA adapter route using the wljmsra.rar (yes, I am aware...Websphere is not on the supported servers list as listed by Oracle https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/JMSRA/intro.htm#JMSRA107)

So any help in achieving this would be much appreciated :)